# Error adding list in loop condition in python

Tags: python, list, loops, while-loop

```
while dir_loop_water < water_lenth:

    ds_water = gdal.Open('path'+ dirlist_water[dir_loop_water] , gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    numer_of_band_water = str(ds_water.RasterCount)
    if numer_of_band_water == '3':
        print('water condition matched')
        rb_water = ds_water.GetRasterBand(1)
        band1_water_tmp = rb_water.ReadAsArray()
        band1_water = band1_water_tmp.tolist()

        rb2_water = ds_water.GetRasterBand(2)
        band2_water_tmp = rb2_water.ReadAsArray()
        band2_water = band2_water_tmp.tolist()

        rb3_water = ds_water.GetRasterBand(3)
        band3_water_tmp = rb3_water.ReadAsArray()
        band3_water = band3_water_tmp.tolist()

        [cols_water,rows_water] = band1_water_tmp.shape
        loop_water_cols = 0

        while loop_water_cols < cols_water:

            loop_water_rows = 0

            while loop_water_rows < rows_water:


                dataset.append([band1_water[loop_water_cols][loop_water_rows],band2_water[loop_water_cols][loop_water_rows],band3_water[loop_water_cols][loop_water_rows],0])

                loop_water_rows = loop_water_rows +1
            del dataset[0]
            with open('path/dataset.csv', 'a') as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f)
                    writer.writerows(dataset)
                    f.close()
            dataset= [None]
            loop_water_cols = loop_water_cols +1
    dir_loop_water= dir_loop_water+1
```

With the above code, I want to add lists with length 4 to dataset.

but i print dataset's value(print(dataset[number])), it print like this.

```
[0.02672404982149601, 0.003426517592743039, 28.19584846496582, 0]
[0.02675003558397293, 0.00344488094560802, 28.192949295043945, 0]
```

In my opinion of above code, I add one list with four values.

However, the result is a combination of two lists with four values.

I could not find where the list would be merged.

Thanks for letting me know how to add only one list with 4 values at a time.

Comment: Your indentation is currently invalid. Please [edit] your question to post the actual working code. In the desktop version of this site, you can paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to have it correctly formatted.

Comment: i'm sorry  about that. i'll edit that

Answer (score 2):

Your dataset.append() method is appending the entire list into your list (making a list of lists).

To append each item of the new list into the dataset (If I'm understanding you correctly) use += like so:

```
dataset += [band1_water[loop_water_cols][loop_water_rows],band2_water[loop_water_cols][loop_water_rows],band3_water[loop_water_cols][loop_water_rows],0]
```

this will result in a list like so:

```
[0.02672404982149601, 0.003426517592743039, 28.19584846496582, 0, 0.02675003558397293, 0.00344488094560802, 28.192949295043945, 0]
```